# Why use a variable instead of this?

Tags: javascript

In a Javascript code example, I saw a professional use a variable instead of the constant this:

```
var self = this;
self.[global_variable] = 0;
```

why do people use a different variable? for some reason, I tried replacing self with this

```
this.[global_variable] = 0;
```

didnt work? How does this happen?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Are you sure you saw: `self.[global_variable] = 0;`, and not `self[global_variable] = 0;`? Because the first looks like a syntax error, at best.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I think he used brackets to mark a metasyntactic variable, not as part of a JavaScript syntax.

Comment: yeah I just used brackets to mark a variables .. lets say self.x

Comment: @Code-Apprentice didnt work meaning this.x = 0 didnt set x to 0

Comment: Please edit your question with a **complete** example that anyone can copy and paste and run themselves.